# How to display json data to table on Html page using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

please im trying to display my json file on html page using angularjs to get the data from a source and displaying the data on a table format whenever the respective link to the data is clicked. I'm new to angular.

---this is my app.js file---

```
  var app = angular.module('dapp',['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/facilities', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/facilties.html',
            controller: 'facilitiesController'
        });

    });
```

----this is my facilities.html page----

```
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-list well">
        <li ng-repeat="facility in facilities" ng-bind="facility.Province">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!--<div ng-repeat="facility in facilities" ><div>Type:{{facility.type}}-->

</div>

<div class="table">
    <p ng-hide="facilities">No facility found</p>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ng-show="facilities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Facility Id</th>
                <th>Name of Facility</th>
                <th>Municipality</th>
                <th>Province</th>
                <th>Year of Construction</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="facility in facilities">
                <td class="span2" ng-bind="facility.id">{{facility.id}}</td>
                <td class="span2" ng-bind="facility.name">{{facility.name}}</td>
                <td class="span2" ng-bind="facility.municipality"></td>
                <td class="span2" ng-bind="facility.province">{{facility.province}}</td>
                <td class="span2" ng-bind="facility.yearOfConstruction"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row controls">
        <form ng-click="fetchFacilities()">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="indoor sport facilities">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

-----this is the function i created for fetching the data----

```
$scope.fetchFacilities = function() { 
     $http.get("thesis-folorunsho.c9users.io/facility").then(function(response) {
         console.info('Facilities:', response.data);      
         $scope.facilities = response.data;      
     }); 
};
```

Comment: ------this is my index.html-----

Comment: Looks ok, just missing a service to get the data

Comment: I still have some other parts of the codes to showw but i couldn't upload them here due to some errors.. I would be glad if anyone can help me through skype... this is my id:
abdulmahjeedibnibrahim..Thanks

Comment: This is the function i created for fetching the data from the url source: $scope.fetchFacilities = function() {
        $http.get("https://thesis-folorunsho.c9users.io/facility")
            .then(function(response) {
                console.info('Facilities:', response.data);
                $scope.facilities = response.data;
            });
    };

Comment: This is the function i created for fetching the data from the url source:

Comment: Please remove the code from comments and put in the question, it's more clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Are you sure that you are recieving the data from the server?

Comment: @GabrieleCiech yes im receiving the data... i tested it already.. my problem is how to use angular to display the data on my html page

Comment: @Folorunsho Do you have sample json data?